# I am doing a python exercise for beginers, and I encountered a problem related to .join()

Tags: python, python-3.x

The question asks to build a program that calculates the square root for input numbers, i figured out how to do the operation, but the output i got has a different format from the one given in the task.

The output of the program should be:
18,22,24

However, mine is like this: [18,22,24]

This is an example answer given:

```
from math import *
C,H = 50,30
def calc(D):
    D = int(D)
    return str(int(sqrt((2*C*D)/H)))
D = input().split(',')
D = list(map(calc,D))   
print(",".join(D))
```

I thought .join() is a string method, and it seems that D here is a list, and the join method works.

This is my answer:

```
import math
c=50
h=30
list_d = input('enter').split(',')
list_q = []
for d in list_d:
    d = float(d)
    q = round(math.sqrt((2*c*d)/h))
    list_q.append(q)
print(''.join(list_q))
```

Somehow, i can't use join method on my list_q and i got an error says:
    print(''.join(list_q))
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found

It's confusing...

Thanks to whoever could explain a little bit!

Comment: You need to change the data type to str instead of int or float.

Comment: that example is using map: `list(map(calc,D))` so not having integer .

Comment: notice the attached answer returns `str(int(...))`, while you only return `round(math.sqrt(...))`. also, you used `''.join(...)` which should be `','.join`.

Comment: You guys are so helpful !!!!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is not with the string you're calling `join` on, or with the list itself, but with the values inside the list. `str.join` expects its argument to be a list of strings, but you're passing it a list of integers. It won't convert them for you!

Fortunately, you can fix the pretty easily. Rather than appending `q` to your list, append `str(q)`. You can see `str` being called in the example function too!